# BringToFront doesn't work inside a coordinator layout

Tags: android, bringtofront

```
Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4
```

I am using to use `BringToFront` to get a `TextView` to display in front of the other controls.

The Doc's [bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29) say you have to call `requestlayout` `invalidate`. Which I do, but doesn't work.

```
tvLevel.bringToFront();
tvLevel.requestLayout();
tvLevel.invalidate();
```

I am using this `TextView` inside a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

However, the following code does work. But only supports API 21 and above. But I need to support API 16.

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      tvLevel.setTranslationZ(4);
      tvLevel.invalidate();
  }
```

Or by setting the `xml` attribute property `android:translationZ("4dp")` works. However, only for API 21

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
   /**
     * Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
     * views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
     * uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior
     * to {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#KITKAT} this
     * method should be followed by calls to {@link #requestLayout()} and
     * {@link View#invalidate()} on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw
     * with the new child ordering.
     *
     * @see ViewGroup#bringChildToFront(View)
     */
    public void bringToFront() {
        if (mParent != null) {
            mParent.bringChildToFront(this);
        }
    }
```

according to this  You may missing the line:

```
((View)myView.getParent()).requestLayout();
```

and it will work, Check it out.!

Comment: With me is inverse, works on android 4.4- but not work in 5.0+, just call bringToFront()+requestLayout()+invalidate()...

Answer (score 9):

`bringToFront()` work for me inside `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. My environment:

- Android Studio 1.5.1
- Device: Motorola with Android 4.1.2 (API 16)

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.bringToFront();
}
```

Here are the screenshots:

With `textView.bringToFront();`

[image]

Without `textView.bringToFront();`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> Prior to KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to
>   requestLayout() and invalidate() **on the view's parent** to force the
>   parent to redraw with the new child ordering.

These methods have to be called on the view's parent. You are calling them on the view itself.

This should work.

```
tvLevel.bringToFront();
tvLevel.getParent().requestLayout();
tvLevel.getParent().invalidate();
```