# BringToFront of the custom view inside a coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bringtofront

Actually there is already similar question
[BringToFront doesn't work inside a coordinator layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469596/bringtofront-doesnt-work-inside-a-coordinator-layout/34506971)

However no of suggestions helped me to make bringToFront work within a coordinatorlayout.

Here is the layout-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
                android:name="..."
                android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/..."
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>

    <CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="..."/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The custom view is inherited from FrameLayout. It can change its height.

To bring the custom view to the front first I tried to add:

```
mCustomView.bringToFront();
```

Then

```
mCustomView.requestLayout();
mCustomView.invalidate();
```

Finally also

```
((View)mCustomView.getParent()).requestLayout();
```

But without success. The button is still on the top.

Did I missed anything?

Maybe there other possibilities to bring the custom view to front or to put the button under custom view?

I also tried to add a behaviour to the button, but since it's visibility depends not only on the custom view I thrown this approach away.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved it at the end?

Comment: @DavidVávra nope. just gave up. But have you tried to upgrade android support library if you don't use the newest one?

Comment: I solved it by translationZ property which works well on API 21+. We will deal with compatibility later. We are using latest support library.

Comment: @DavidVávra we can't use it, we need to support API 14+

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a workaround - if I set `setEnabled(false)` on the AppBar, it goes to the background and I can draw other stuff over it regardless of API level.